# Launch activity faster with recyclerview UI from another activity

Tags: android, performance

I have a `RecyclerView`. When an item is pressed, another `Activity` with another `RecyclerView` appears. The problem is that the second `Activity` needs a few seconds for loading. I want to make the `Application` more responsive launching the `Activity` before the `RecyclerView` `Adapter` is ready. In other words, I want that the loading time to be spent in the second `Activity` will not in the first one, so when the user clicks on the first `Activity` the second `Activity` appears immediately but without the items that will load after a second. I saw that the `Activity` is launched after `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` .
Is there any way to launch the `Activity` after setting the `Adapter`?

**Java Code**

```
private void firstTimeMatchLoader(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    bet = intent.getParcelableExtra("all_match");
    uri = intent.getData();
    if(bet == null){
        Thread loadMatchesFromMemory = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{DocumentContentProvider.Columns.OCR_TEXT}, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String text = c.getString(c.getPosition());
                HashMatchUtil util = new HashMatchUtil();
                allMatch = util.fromStringToArray(text);
                bet = new SingleBet(allMatch);
                singleBetAdapter = new SingleBetAdapter(SingleBetActivity.this,bet);
                singleBetAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                rVSingleBet.setAdapter(singleBetAdapter);
                allMatchLoadListener.onMatchesLoaded();
                singleBetAdapter.setOutsideClickListener(new ActivityClickListener());
                singleBetAdapter.setDialogListener(new DialogClickListener());
            }
        });
        loadMatchesFromMemory.start();
    }
    else{
        allMatch = bet.getArrayMatch();
        singleBetAdapter = new SingleBetAdapter(SingleBetActivity.this, bet);
        singleBetAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        rVSingleBet.setAdapter(singleBetAdapter);
        allMatchLoadListener.onMatchesLoaded();
        singleBetAdapter.setOutsideClickListener(new ActivityClickListener());
        singleBetAdapter.setDialogListener(new DialogClickListener());
    }
}
```

I want the loadMatchesFromMemory thread execute after the activity is created.

Comment: You could provide some code of a minimal example so it's easier for people to understand your problem and answer it